# VLOOKUP is not matching properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a multisheet excel file where I am in sheet3 and trying to find the data for a person in sheet2 but it doesn't match correctly, it gets the data of another person. 
So I am trying to get the number of days for "Tim" from sheet2:

[image]

but is shows like that:

[image]

The code is I used was `=VLOOKUP($B81,sheet2!$A$2:$M$281,2)`

Comment: try `=VLOOKUP($B81,sheet2!$A$2:$M$281,2,FALSE)` or `=VLOOKUP($B81,sheet2!$A$2:$M$281,2,0)` if you want exact match. You are missing the last argument in your original formula.

Comment: It worked! so what does the last argument do?

Comment: it's Get exact match of the finding value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
=VLOOKUP($B81,sheet2!$A$2:$M$281,2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP($B81,sheet2!$A$2:$M$281,2,0)
```

if you want exact match.

The last argument of the **VLOOKUP** function determines the nature of your look up.

`1 - TRUE` will return an approximate match which is useful when you want to look up a value from group of ranges in ascending order;

`0 - FALSE` will return an exact match which will return the first match based on your look up criteria.

> If you do not input the last argument in your formula, Excel will presume you want to use `1 - TRUE` and do an approximate match which will look up the closest (and smaller) match of `Tim` such as `Sam` which is considered ahead of `Tim` and return the value corresponding to `Sam` instead. However, if your formula is `=VLOOKUP($B81,sheet2!$A$2:$M$281,2,)` with a comma `,` at the end of `2`, Excel will presume you want to use `0 - FALSE` and do an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

**Terry W** already answered about the exact match, however here you go for some more trail which helps you to work with v-look up easier way.

**Table Of RAW Data**

[image]

Table Of Sheet 2, where we need values of **TIM**

Trail 1 (Used For Jan):

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,Raw!A1:M4,2)
```

Which is worked without using exact match function, as you tired.

Trail 2 (Used For Jan):

```
 VLOOKUP(A4,Raw!A1:M4,2,0)
```

Which is worked using exact match function as "0", as you tired.

Trail 3 (Used For Jan):

```
 =VLOOKUP($B10,Raw!$A$1:$M$4,MATCH(C$9,Raw!$A$1:$M$1,0),0)
```

Here instead of using the **Index_Num** Used match function and used Exact Match Argument too. The match function helps to get exact value of the month, and which make work easier instead of mentioning the **Index_Num** as 1 and 2 and 3 and Ext... for next and next months. Below snap is for your view.

[image]

> Please let me know if need any more clarification need on this.